# How i can add a list of JLabels in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a list of labels in java swing.

Main Code:

```
JLabel local = new JLabel();
local.setBackground(new Color(186, 79, 84));
local.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 10));
local.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
local.setText("Local");


JTable list = new JTable(new JLabel[][]{{local}}, new String[]{"Local"});
```

But it's giving me a little problem.

[image: Error]

What would be the best way, the goal would be to create a vertical list with one item on each line.

[image: Objective]

Comment: Don't add components to a JTable. What you see is the "toString()" text of the component added. Just add the text to the table and the table will render the text using a JLabel. And yes, if you only have a single column then use a `JList`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for examples. If you want different fonts and colors then use properties of the JList.

Comment: If you further on want more control,  implement your own TableCellRenderer.